# How can I merge 2 zip files into 1?

Tags: c#, zip, unzip

i have 2 zip files (zip1 and zip2), i need merge this files in one, how can i solve it?
I understand that I can fix it decompressing ZIP1 to a temp folder and then add it to zip2, but i think it is inefficient, what is the faster method?

I'm using `System.IO.Compression` library...

I use this code to explore Zip2:

```
 using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(Zip2))
 {
    foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
    {
       /*...*/
    }
 }
```

PD/: The Zip1 and Zip2 files have **FILES, FOLDERS AND SUBFOLDERS**

Comment: What size of zip files are we talking about? A few MB? A few GB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't really tested this, but you can give it a try:

```
    public ZipArchive Merge(List<ZipArchive> archives)
    {
        if (archives == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("archives");
        if (archives.Count == 1) return archives.Single();

        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var archive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
            {
                foreach (var zipArchive in archives)
                {
                    foreach (var zipArchiveEntry in zipArchive.Entries)
                    {
                        var file = archive.CreateEntry(zipArchiveEntry.FullName);

                        using (var entryStream = file.Open()) {
                            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(entryStream)) { streamWriter.Write(zipArchiveEntry.Open()); }
                        }
                    }
                }

                return archive;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, but first you need read stream `zipArchiveEntry.Open()` to write it in `StreamWriter` i solve it with `StreamReader`

Comment: How I save the resultant zip (archive) to a specific folder? I mean how I save it as a file?

Answer (score 1):

I had an equivalent problem. The zip files came from another process as byte arrays. This method adds their contents to an existing ZipArchive.

```
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;

        /// <summary>
        /// Copies the contents of a zip "file" represented as a byte array
        /// to the given ZipArchive.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="targetArchive">The archive to which to add the entries.</param>
        /// <param name="zippedSourceBuffer">The source data as zip "file" in a byte array.</param>
        public static void addZipBufferToZipArchive(ZipArchive targetArchive, byte[] zippedSourceBuffer)
        {
            using (MemoryStream zippedSourceStream = new MemoryStream(zippedSourceBuffer))
            {
                using (ZipArchive sourceArchive = new ZipArchive(zippedSourceStream))
                {
                    foreach (ZipArchiveEntry sourceEntry in sourceArchive.Entries)
                    {
                        ZipArchiveEntry targetEntry = targetArchive.CreateEntry(sourceEntry.FullName);
                        using (Stream targetEntryStream = targetEntry.Open())
                        {
                            using (Stream sourceStream = sourceEntry.Open())
                            {
                                sourceStream.CopyTo(targetEntryStream);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

There does not appear to be any way to directly move a ZipArchiveEntry from one ZipArchive to another, so I resorted to unpacking the source and repacking it to the target via the copy operation.

If you already have a ZipArchive as source, you wouldn't need the MemoryStream zippedSourceStream and could modify the code to use sourceArchive directly as the method parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This example shows how to merge two zip files into third one in memory or with actual files with the help of [DotNetZip](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetZip/) library:

```
//file1 and file2 are MemoryStream or file names
//for performance reason it is better that file1 is less than file2

//file1.Position = 0;//ensure at case of MemoryStream
using (var zip1 = ZipFile.Read(file1))
{
    //file2.Position = 0;//ensure at case of MemoryStream
    using (var zip2 = ZipFile.Read(file2))
    {
        var zip2EntryNames = zip2.Entries.Select(y => y.FileName).ToList();
        foreach (var entry in zip1.Entries.Where(x => !zip2EntryNames.Contains(x.FileName)).ToList())
        {
            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            entry.Extract(memoryStream);
            memoryStream.Position = 0;
            zip2.AddEntry(entry.FileName, memoryStream);
        }
        if(save2file)
            zip2.Save(fileNameResult);
        else
            using (var result = new MemoryStream())
            {
                zip2.Save(result);                        
            }
    }
}
```