# exception when trying to merge two streams into one

Tags: c#

I give an example of two of my methods that return a stream to memory. my main goal is to bring them together

I want to merge two archives (which are in memory) into one archive (into one stream)

```
public static Task<Stream> GetText()
{
   MemoryStream result = new MemoryStream();
   ZipStorer storer = ZipStorer.Create(result, "");
   {
       byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("This is my Text");
       
       MemoryStream h = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
       storer.AddStream(ZipStorer.Compression.Deflate, "example.txt", h, DateTime.Now, null);
   }
   storer.ZipFileStream.Position = 0;
   storer.ZipFileStream.CopyTo(result);
   storer.Close();

   return Task.FromResult(result as Stream);
}

public static Task<Stream> GetTwoText()
{
   MemoryStream result = new MemoryStream();
   ZipStorer storer = ZipStorer.Create(result, "");
   {
       byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("TWOWOWOWOWOWO");
       
       MemoryStream h = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
       storer.AddStream(ZipStorer.Compression.Deflate, "exampleTWO.txt", h, DateTime.Now, null);
   }
   storer.ZipFileStream.Position = 0;
   storer.ZipFileStream.CopyTo(result);
   storer.Close();

   return Task.FromResult(result as Stream);
}
```

here I am trying to combine them into one archive using threads and asynchrony

```
class Program
{
   static async Task Main()
   {
       var list = new List<Task<Stream>> { GetText(), GetTwoText() };
       Stream stream = await list.Select(async item => await item).Aggregate((current, next) => Task.FromResult(current.Result.Append(next.Result)));

       File.WriteAllBytes("ghbrj.zip", (stream as MemoryStream).ToArray());
   }
}

public static class Extensions
{
   public static Stream Append(this Stream destination, Stream source)
   {
       destination.Position = destination.Length;
       source.CopyTo(destination);

       return destination;
   }
}
```

only I get an exception. I assume this is due to the fact that one of the threads is closed

```
?????????????? ??????????: System.ObjectDisposedException: ?????? ? ????????? ?????? ??????????.
   ? System.IO.__Error.StreamIsClosed()
   ? System.IO.MemoryStream.get_Length()
   ? build.Extensions.Append(Stream destination, Stream source)
   ? build.Program.<>c.<Main>b__0_1(Task`1 current, Task`1 next)
   ? System.Linq.Enumerable.Aggregate[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`3 func)
   ? build.Program.<Main>d__0.MoveNext()
--- ????? ??????????? ????? ?? ??????????? ????????????, ??? ???????? ?????????? ---
   ? System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   ? System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   ? build.Program.<Main>()
```

please tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: This code is both single threaded and entirely synchronous.  There is no multithreading or asynchrony here.  That you're wrapping some of the values in tasks does nothing to change that.

Comment: I'm confused as to why you have two methods that are exactly the same with the exception of two strings.  Why not have one method and pass in the strings as parameters?  Also, what exactly is your end goal?

Comment: @devlin-carnate I gave an example, in my code these methods are different, but they both return a memory stream, as in the above code

Comment: jan please review [MCVE] guidance on posting code. As @Servy said the code is completely synchronous so you can drop all `Task` / `async` from the sample,  there is no much need of Zip (you can just `new MemoryStream(new byte[]{1,2,3})`), maybe there is no need for `Aggregate` (or maybe it is the reason) - basically 4-5 lines of code in a single function should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

> storer.Close();

This line will close your stream. See source code: https://github.com/jaime-olivares/zipstorer/blob/master/src/ZipStorer.cs

You have to tell ZipStorer to leave the stream open:

```
ZipStorer.Create(result, "", true);
```

Here's the signature:

```
/// <param name="_leaveOpen">true to leave the stream open after the ZipStorer object is disposed; otherwise, false (default).</param>
public static ZipStorer Create(Stream _stream, string _comment = null, bool _leaveOpen = false)
```

Comment: Thanks! in this case, I get a broken archive, but the archive is being created, and it has example.txt (a exampleTWO.txt no)

Comment: That's because you cannot merge zip files by simply merging the files.

Comment: how then can two archives be combined? if this is not possible using memorystream

Comment: It's just Google and the first result but the second answer looks like a copy and paste solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28035453/how-can-i-merge-2-zip-files-into-1